# Is it possible to have login geoblock for AWS Management Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

I was looking for the such functionality in AWS, but, didn't found anything like this. Google offers to restrict access to the regions and CloudFront. This is the reason why I came here. We have had a security incident, not AWS related. We have introduced geoblock for some of our resources and systems. We would like to do the same geoblocking for AWS's console.

We have all the accounts in the organization. I managed only to implement SCP to whitelist our HQ IP and a few more IPs which denies most of sensetive actions outside. Also, I got an alarm to notify us if somebody logins outside of HQ. But, we have a few contractors working with AWS and the alarm gets triggered often.

I just want to cut access to the console from countries, especially from "russian federation". And to keep our and contractor's. All within the EU. Just to clarify, we already limit access to the regions for us by scp. But, the task is completely different for now.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the closest solution to your problem is to restrict the range of IP addresses from which your AWS resources are accessible. To do this, you need to create an identity-based policy using the IAM condition keys "aws:SourceIp"  you need to create an identity-based policy with the IAM `aws:SourceIp` and `aws:ViaAWSService` condition keys that denies access to all actions outside the specified IP address range.

Example:

```json
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "IpAddress": {
      "aws:SourceIp": [
         "good IP"...
       ]
     }
    }
  }
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-sourceip

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-viaawsservice